# WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing 1180

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection.

I am trying to insert the following record using mongoose.

```
   {
     "employeeColumns": {
                "headCount": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process"],
                "headCountRatio": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process"],
                "genderRatio": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process","gender"],
                "averageCtc": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process","ctc"],
                "accuracy": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process","accuracy"],
                "productivity": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process","productivity"],
                "attrition": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process","employmentStatus"],
                "allowances": ["empId","designation","country","city","branch","vertical","client","process"]
            },
            "costColumns": {
                "branchCost": ["country","city","branch"],
                "clientCost": ["client"],
                "verticalCost": ["vertical"]
            },
            "revenueColumns": ["client"]
    }
```

When i try to insert the above document i am getting the following error

`WiredTigerIndex :: insert: key too large to index, failing  1180`

I am not inserting a huge record. Just the above document and I don't know why I am getting this error. I am relatively new to MongoDB

Comment: Looks like you created an index on all ( or at least more than one ) of the fields with the arrays. This is a constraint in MongoDB that you are not allowed to do that and will get such an error when you try. You don't get an error when the index is created of course since MongoDB is "schemaless" and does not know in advance that the fields you defined in the index are intended to contain such arrays. See [Multikey Indexes - Limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) in the documentation. You would be better served by looking at alternate structures.

Comment: @Neil Thanks. I have changed my schema.